# Ubuntu half-detects one of my external monitors

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, hdmi

I have dual booted laptop running Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04. I used to connect two external monitors (One dell and another Lenovo monitor) through USB-C thunderbolt to two hdmi adapter and it used to work perfectly on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Recently my Ubuntu started giving trouble while Windows still works just fine. On Ubuntu, it detects only single external monitor while it seem to have some issue with second monitor. It lists both external monitors in drop down (check in below screenshot), but shows only single monitor (with number 3 in below screen shot) in image. As you can see Lenovo monitor (number 2 in drop down) has trouble getting properly detected.

[image]

I dont recall myself installing anything new in recent days. Also both monitors work without any issue on Windows.

PS: I have Lenovo C940 14IIL.